# Set common scope variables in run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a web application with **AngularJS** and I would like to know how I can set some `$scope` variables that are commons to all my controllers (or great part of them).

What I am trying:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location, Common) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      //Set default global values
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
        $scope.universe = "Universe and other things :)";
        $scope.elsewhere = "Good day sir";
        $scope.fish = "Perfectly well";
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So I don't have to write everytime the same thing in every controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
  //I don't want this:
  $scope.universe = "Universe and other things :)";
});

angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('Controller2', function($scope) {
  //I don't want this:
  $scope.elsewhere = "Good day sir";
});

angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('Controller3', function($scope) {
  //I don't want this:
  $scope.fish = "Perfectly well";
});
```

The important thing is that **I don't even want** to use `services` for this purpose, because I don't want the assignments in every controller.

Comment: This `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess'...` should work, that's what I usually do. I would usually do a controller, say `AppCtrl`, and add `ng-controller="AppCtrl"` to my `<html>` tag and then in the controller, I would add `$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess'...` and set my "shared" scope variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to my comment:

This is what I would do, create a controller for my app, which would be my "global" stuff.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.universe = "Universe and other things :)";
        $scope.elsewhere = "Good day sir";
        $scope.fish = "Perfectly well";
    });

});
```

And add this to your HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myAppName" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

So this will create a seperate `$scope`, to access that scope from other "child" controllers, you'd do `$scope.$parent`.

However, if we take your original code, this should work:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location, Common) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      //Set default global values
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
        $rootScope.universe = "Universe and other things :)";
        $rootScope.elsewhere = "Good day sir";
        $rootScope.fish = "Perfectly well";
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And then you'd be able to use `$rootScope` in your controllers, or `universe` and etc in your HTML/views.

Comment: Second solution is ok. But what if I wanted to use `$scope` directly and not `$rootScope` in my controllers?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to, as you can't set anything on a `$scope` that you don't have access to. Good chance that they aren't even created when you call Since all the controllers create their own isolated `$scope`, there isn't any way, unless you use a service/provider/etc, to inject anything in that `$scope`. However, pretty sure angular-ui-router provides a `currentScope` property in event. I'd fiddle with that.

Comment: I tried to play with the `currentScope` property but when I set it, it seems that it isn't visible in the controller as `$scope`. [Take a look here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

Comment: Umm, when you're using `$stateChangeSuccess` on `$rootScope`, `currentScope` might represent `$rootScope`. Your best bet will be using `$rootScope` in the controllers.